# Increasing the size of \square?

Tags: boxes

Beginner here! All I want to do is make a couple of boxes on my document. I'm currently using this:

```
\makebox[10pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.4em}$\texttt{1}$}
```

but I need to make the actual boxes bigger. Is there any way to do this? I tried searching, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to increase the `\square`, not the `\makebox`, right?

Comment: Yeah my apologies, that's what I meant. Oops.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're after, but adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble, you can now do `\scalebox{2}{$\square$}` or `\resizebox{50pt}{!}{$\square$}`. However, what is your end goal? Perhaps there are better ways to do what you're after...

Comment: Well then, that worked a lot better. I'm just doing a basic questionnaire in attempt to learn a bit of Latex, and the boxes were a bit too small, that's all. Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: (And welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.)

Comment: @Alex: You can also use `\fbox{<stuff>}` to insert a framed box.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution without symbols, using only the standard `\framebox` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\boxnumber}[1]{%
  \begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% no padding in \framebox
  \raisebox{-.15ex}{% shift slightly down
    \framebox[\ht\strutbox]{%
      \rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}% % fill the height
      \raisebox{.15ex}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \makebox[0pt]{\ttfamily #1}% the number, shifted up
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule height 0pt depth .1pt width 2cm}% to show the baseline
\boxnumber{1}\quad First

\boxnumber{2}\quad Second

\end{document}
```

The `\makebox` in the document is just to show that the number is correctly placed on the baseline.

[image]